# WholeFileRecordReader cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, casting

I wanted to create a new datatype in Hadoop but I get the following error from my custom inputformat class Here is my code :

error - WholeFileRecordReader cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader

code  -

import java.io.IOException;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptContext;



 public class wholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, apriori>{

public RecordReader<Text, apriori> getRecordReader(
          InputSplit input, JobConf job, Reporter reporter)
          throws IOException {

        reporter.setStatus(input.toString());

    return (RecordReader<Text, apriori>) new WholeFileRecordReader(job,FileSplit)input);

      }

}
```

My custom Record Reader is as follows

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;

 class WholeFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text, apriori> {


private FileSplit fileSplit;
private Configuration conf;
private InputStream in;
private Text key = new Text("");
private apriori value = new apriori();
private boolean processed = false;


public void initialize( JobConf job, FileSplit split)
        throws IOException {

    this.fileSplit = split;
    this.conf = job;
    final Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
    String StringPath = new String(fileSplit.getPath().toString());
    String StringPath2 = new String();
    StringPath2 = StringPath.substring(5);
    System.out.println(StringPath2);
    in = new FileInputStream(StringPath2);

    FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
    in = fs.open(file);
    }


public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (!processed) {
        byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
        Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
        key.set(file.getName());

        try {
            IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
            value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }

        processed = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return key;
}

@Override
public apriori getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return value;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
    return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    // Do nothing
}

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Can you share the fully qualified name of the WholeFileRecordReader class .

Comment: Hi sir, donut I have edited my query..

Answer (score 0):

`WholeFileRecordReader` class is a subclass of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader` class.This class cannot be cast to a `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader` class.Can you try using same APIs in both the classes

As per rules of Java programming language only classes or interfaces (collectively known as Type) from same Type hierarchy can be cast or converted into each other. If you try to cast two object which doesn't share same type hierarchy, i.e. there is no parent child relationship between them, you will get compile time error.You can refer this [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

There was package mismatch due to which this error was coming.

In your code you combined both MRv1 and MRv2 due to which you got the error.

Packages `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` is Mrv1. (Map Reduce version 1)

Packages `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` is Mrv2. (Map Reduce version 2)

***In your code you combined both MRv1 and MRv2:***

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
```

Either use all the import packages as `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` (MRv1) or `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` (MRv2).

Hope this helps.